# "R" symbol for the set of real numbers in Microsoft Equation 3.0

Tags: ms-word

How can one insert the R symbol for the real numbers into an equation using Microsoft Equation 3.0 available in MS Word? I mean this [double struck capital ℝ](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/211d/index.htm).

I struggle with it and have already tried: 
- Copy and paste 
- Convert ASCII Hexadecimal Code **211D** into the wished symbol 
- Use the special font as Cambria Math and others

All these options perfectly work in the running text, but not in formulas! 
Make my day and tell me that it's possible (must be in MS Equation).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the MS Equation environment select the style of object as "Other" (Style/Other).
And then choose the font „Euclid Math Two“. It works only for the big letters, so SHIFT+R gives the wished ℝ symbol. It also allows to produce double struck ℂ, ℚ, etc.

I found the answer by myself and met many others who were searching for it. This is an easy solution.

**EDIT:**

There are TWO build-in options how to input equations into Word. We need to distinguish between them!

i) MS Word's native equation format - \doubleR (font "Cambria Math")

ii) MS Equation 3.0 (MathType Equation Editor as its fancy version, my original question) - SHIFT+R after installing font "Euclid Math Two" and setting it as the style of object (in menu, set font)

In addition, look at [any source](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-Font-in-Microsoft-Word) how to add font and embed your font in the document if you want to share it.

Comment: Where is this Style/Other to be found? I have a german office version and having a hard time finding this :(

Comment: Menu, MS Equation. Together with: Style/Math, Style/Text, Style/Function, Style/Variable, Style/Greek, Style/Matrix-Vector and finally Style/Other...

Comment: I should say I have office 2010, and there it's a bit different, but upon closer inspection I found it: it's next to the "Symbols" table, the down arrow with the line on top of it, and in the dialog popping up under "letter-like symbols"

Answer (score 77):

in equation editor, type in \doubleR. (A shortcut to enter equation editor is ALT and +)

Comment: I asked about MS Equation editor, not the Word's native equation. These are two different things. It cannot be marked as the best one. Look at my edited answer below.

Comment: use \doubleC, \doubleN etc. for the other ones. These letters are known as "double-struck" as stated in one of the other answers.

Answer (score 15):

The character ℝ can be found in the symbols list under the font Cambria Math in the Letterlike Subject set.  I set an auto-correct option so that if I type `$real` it will automatically insert this symbol.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the cambria math font. Most symbols are in that font and can be inserted using insert->symbol and selecting that font.

For this specific sign, it is possible to insert the Unicode 211D in the insert symbol window instead of searching for it.

Answer (score 14):

to enter real numbers R (double-struck), complex numbers C, natural numbers N use
\doubleR, \doubleC, \doubleN, etc. and press the space bar.  This style is commonly known as double-struck.

Answer (score 9):

Try `\mathbb{\doubleR}`. It works in my case using 2016. It will probably work in yours too, hopefully.

Answer (score 3):

I found it the easiest solution:

- Press ALT and =.
- Go to **Ink Equation.**
- Draw and insert the symbol.

Answer (score 1):

In the new MS Word, just type \doubleR and space

Answer (score 0):

Use Unicode (hex) instead of Ascii (Hex), insert Character code: 211D in Microsoft Office: Insert --> Symbol, it will insert double struck capital R for real nos. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

find equation Editor and then find the design tab under it. Then you can click the extended icon for drop-down selection list. That dropdown list contains `Letter-like symbols` section for select. This section you can see many mathematical symbols for use.

Answer (score 0):

For double strike R, Z, etc. use Font Euclid Math Two

Answer (score -1):

The Unicode for natural number is 2115

Comment: I think OP was asking for the symbol for all real numbers, ℝ. Not natural numbers, ℕ.

Comment: Also, how does knowing the unicode code point help with entering it using a keyboard?